# Android Studio Error Communicating With System CMake

Tags: android-studio, cmake

I just created a trivial Android project with C++ support using Android Studio 3.0.1 on OS X High Sierra and I'm trying to figure out how to get CMake support.

I wasn't able to install CMake through Android Studio because there's an error with the project and the `Tools > Android` option is not available through the menu.

Here's what the project looks like:

[image: without-android-tools]

For comparison, here's another trivial project without C++ support showing the `Tools > Android` option.

[image: with-android-tools]

I read something about configuring Android Studio to use the system `cmake`. Apparently, you can override the `cmake.dir` setting in the project's `local.properties` file:

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

excerpt:

> Include the path to the CMake installation in your project's
>
> `local.properties file: cmake.dir="path-to-cmake"`

So, I set the `cmake.dir` to `/usr/local` (because I already installed `cmake` previously through homebrew and changed the properties file)

It now reads (replacing `~` with your home directory)

```
# ... some comments warning you not to modify
# the properties file ...
ndk.dir=~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=~/Library/Android/sdk
cmake.dir="/usr/local"
```

Android Studio now shows the error message (newlines and `\`s inserted for legibility and home directory replaced with `~`):

```
Error:Error occurred while communicating with CMake server. 
Check log 
~/AndroidStudioProjects/Cpptest/
\ app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/
\ debug/armeabi-v7a/cmake_server_log.txt
for additional information.
```

However, the contents of that file suggest that the `cmake` binary did something reasonable in response to a command invoked by Android Studio.

```
CMAKE SERVER:-

CMAKE SERVER: [== "CMake Server" ==[

CMAKE SERVER: {"supportedProtocolVersions":[{"isExperimental":true,"major":1,"minor":1}],"type":"hello"}

CMAKE SERVER: ]== "CMake Server" ==]
```

The system CMake is version `3.10.0` which is greater than `3.7` (I believe the minimum supported version).

- How do I "convince" Android Studio to use the system CMake?
- Is there a way to install a CMake distribution managed by the IDE if `Tools > Android` is not available?
- If neither of those options seems straightforward, can I configure Android Studio to use a different build system for the C++ sources, like GNU Make or just plain gradle?

Comment: Gregory, according to https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#vanilla_cmake: _Support for using CMake 3.7 and higher with Android Studio is a preview feature.  If you experience any issues, please report a bug._ 

If you submitted a bug, please share the link.

Comment: After more digging, I found this bug report (which references your post): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70378585

This issue might be related to adding support for CMake Server v1.1:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70677697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I still don't know why pointing Android Studio at the system CMake didn't work. I also tried installing a "full CMake" distribution through their website (https://cmake.org/download/) and pointing to `/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/`

However, it is possible to install `CMake` and `lldb` in a different way in Android Studio on OS X even if `Tools > Android` Does not appear.

And that is:

```
Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools
```

Or, equivalently, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd> and then type `sdk` in the search field and then click the `SDK Tools` tab.

Here's a picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue in earlier versions of external CMake support where we didn't support future CMake server protocol versions. This has since been fixed. If you try a recent Android Studio 3.1 I think it should work.

Comment: I run into the same issue with CMake 3.12.1 on Android Studio 3.1.4 Build #AI-173.4907809. Except the "supportedProtocolVersions" reports 1.2 instead of 1.1 compared to OP.